# ValueError: Shapes (100, 1) and (100, 28, 19, 1, 1) are incompatible

Tags: python, keras

So I've been trying to create a simple convolutional net with mnist, but upon running it, the following was produced:     `ValueError: Shapes (100, 1) and (100, 28, 19, 1, 1) are incompatible`

I checked all my sample dimensions, but none creates this. Is there any way to avoid it?
here is the code

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

(x_train_full, y_train_full), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
img = Image.open('testimg.png')
img.thumbnail((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
x_train_full = x_train_full.reshape(list(x_train_full.shape) + [1])
x_valid, x_train = x_train_full[:5000] / 255.0, x_train_full[5000:] / 255.0
y_valid, y_train = y_train_full[:5000], y_train_full[5000:]
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(1, (1, 1), input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(10, (10, 1), input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(1, (1, 1), input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=100, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid), use_multiprocessing=True)
res = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, 128)
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need 1 `input_shape=`, the first one. It is used to create the graph network and you can calculate the output shape which will become the input shape of the next layer. So

```
model.add(Conv2D(1, (1, 1), input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(10, (10, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='softmax'))
```

Should runs past that error, but you'll stuck somewhere else as mnist dataset need the output to be rank 2 tensor while your model will return rank 4. You have to change `'softmax'` from the last `Conv2D` to `'relu'` and add

```
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

But I doubt CNN model with 1 or 10 kernels and no pooling layers will give you any good result though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! also, should i define the dimensions on Dense as well?